# Missing dependency error occurs frequently

Tags: dependency-injection, jersey, guice

I am using google guice as  DI framework to bind my interfaces to the different Implementation. The server operates normally but whenever i try to call the Resource class the following error occurs. It is not that the binding never works but  most of time  it fails. I don't  know what i am missing . I've given some of my source code  below.

ModuleClass

```
public class ABCModule extends AbstractModule {
@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(IConnection.class).to(ABCConnection.class);
}
```

Resource class where injection is done

```
public class Resource {

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Resource.class);
private final IContact contact;
private final IContactFolder contactFolder;

@Inject
public MLContact(IConnection con, IContactFolder contactFolder) {
    this.contact = contact;
    this.con = con;
    this.contactFolder = contactFolder;
   }
   //Resource class methods
    ..
     ......
}
```

I am using guice-3.0.jar

EDIT 1:

```
   INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.17 01/17/2013 04:27 PM'   Aug 8, 2013 9:54:59 AM com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors processErrorMessages
   SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
   SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.motilink.server.services.MLContact(com.motilink.connector.IContact,com.motilink.connector.IConnection,com.motilink.connector.IContactFolder) at parameter index 0
   SEVERE: Missing dependency for constructor public com.motilink.server.services.MLContact(com.motilink.connector.IContact,com.motilink.connector.IConnection,com.motilink.connector.IContactFolder) at parameter index 1
```

Comment: Which error was that? Generally Guice errors are pretty descriptive, so posting the trace will help a lot.

Comment: I've posted my error log in the EDIT 1 above. This might help you to find solution for my problem.

Comment: It looks like you posted a constructor for `MLContact` inside your `Resources` class. More importantly, you have only showed us an `@Inject-annotated` two-argument constructor for `MLContact`, while the trace you posted alludes to a three-argument constructor.